# Isolating regions of data based on multiple columns

Tags: r, intervals, subset

I have a dataset, abbreviated here:

```
SNP chr       BP log10   PPA
rs10068  17 56555 1.16303 0.030
rs10032  17 56561 26.364 0.975
rs10354  17 34951 4.3212 0.626
rs10043  17 20491 0.00097 0.006
rs10457  17 69572 -0.38403 0.014
rs10465  17 69872 8.19547 0.927
```

where PPA is the posterior probability of association. As I have some high log10 values (>6), I would like to determine credible intervals around these regions, to determine exactly how large or small they are with confidence.

To do this, I would first like to identify SNPs with a log10 > 6, which is simple enough using subset.

```
newdata <- subset(data, log10 > 6)
```

However, I would also like to include in this subset, SNPs that are physically near these lead SNPs, using BP 500 +/- the BP of the lead SNPs (with log10>6). It is here where I am unsure the best way to proceed. Is this something I can work into `subset` or should I first identify these lead SNPs in my original data, and then subset from there?

Once I isolate these regions, I can move forward.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How many SNPs do you have (or how many rows?)

Comment: @Arun, tags are for questions, not answers.  This question ultimately has nothing to do with any of the tags you are adding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s <- read.table(header=T, text="SNP chr       BP log10   PPA
rs10068  17 56555 1.16303 0.030
rs10032  17 56561 26.364 0.975
rs10354  17 34951 4.3212 0.626
rs10043  17 20491 0.00097 0.006
rs10457  17 69572 -0.38403 0.014
rs10465  17 69872 8.19547 0.927")
```

Distance to any row where s$log10 > 6:

```
outer(s$BP[s$log10 > 6], s$BP, '-')
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
## [1,]     6     0 21610 36070 -13011 -13311
## [2,] 13317 13311 34921 49381    300      0
```

Any column above with an absolute value < 500 is one that you want to keep:

```
s[apply(outer(s$BP[s$log10 > 6], s$BP, '-'), 2, function(x) any(abs(x) < 500)),]
##       SNP chr    BP    log10   PPA
## 1 rs10068  17 56555  1.16303 0.030
## 2 rs10032  17 56561 26.36400 0.975
## 5 rs10457  17 69572 -0.38403 0.014
## 6 rs10465  17 69872  8.19547 0.927
```

Comment: (+1) very nice use of `outer`! I suspect there might be a follow-up question on doing this by splitting by `chr` column.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's a solution using `GenomicRanges` package. This package builds on `IRanges` and handles interval data very efficiently using `interval trees`. And this should be able to handle all different chromosomes as well.

- First load data:

  ```
  # load data
  df <- read.table(header=T, text="SNP chr       BP log10   PPA
  rs10068  17 56555 1.16303 0.030
  rs10032  17 56561 26.364 0.975
  rs10354  17 34951 4.3212 0.626
  rs10043  17 20491 0.00097 0.006
  rs10457  17 69572 -0.38403 0.014
  rs10465  17 69872 8.19547 0.927")
  ```
- Get subset where log10 > 6

  ```
  df.f <- df[df$log10 > 6, ]
  ```
- Load and create Ranges on the initial data and the subset

  ```
  require(GenomicRanges)
  df.gr <- GRanges(Rle(df$chr), IRanges(df$BP, df$BP))
  df.f.gr <- GRanges(Rle(df.f$chr), IRanges(df.f$BP, df.f$BP))
  ```
- Find all overlaps of data with log10 > 6 with all other SNPs with gap = +/- 500

  ```
  olaps <- findOverlaps(df.f.gr, df.gr, maxgap=500)
  ```
- Get output

  ```
  # if you just want a whole data.frame with ALL SNPs that have 
  # log > 6 or within 500 bases of one with log > 6, then,        
  out <- df[subjectHits(olaps), ] 

  #       SNP chr    BP    log10   PPA
  # 1 rs10068  17 56555  1.16303 0.030
  # 2 rs10032  17 56561 26.36400 0.975
  # 5 rs10457  17 69572 -0.38403 0.014
  # 6 rs10465  17 69872  8.19547 0.927

  # In case you want for each SNP that has log > 6, all of the 
  # snps that are within 500 bases (either side) apart for 
  # this SNP, separately, then,
  out.list <- split(out, df$BP[queryHits(olaps)])
  # $`56555`
  #       SNP chr    BP    log10   PPA
  # 1 rs10068  17 56555  1.16303 0.030
  # 2 rs10032  17 56561 26.36400 0.975
  #     
  # $`56561`
  #       SNP chr    BP    log10   PPA
  # 5 rs10457  17 69572 -0.38403 0.014
  # 6 rs10465  17 69872  8.19547 0.927
  ```

Comment: This is great, too! The split in ranges is very useful. One question, I'm having an issue writing the output (out.list) to a file. I've tried `write`, `cat`, & `sink`, but my syntax must be off. R keeps giving me variations of the error: `argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`. How do I fix this? Or, is it possible to remove the rows containing `$` so I can use `write.table`?

Comment: I guess you are using the second solution, which is a `list`? If so, you must convert it to a `data.frame` first. The easiest way is `require(plyr)` followed by `ldply(out.list)`. Now, you'll have an extra column that was the list element's name. And its a data.frame. you should be able to write to file.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! It's also useful to have the `.id` column specific to the isolated regions. I appreciate your help!